# What are the differences between QueryRow and Exec in Golang SQL package?

Tags: sql, go, transactions

In Golang SQL package there are QueryRow and Exec for executing query. If I'm executing insertion query inside transaction, which is better to be used in term of performance?

`err = tx.QueryRow(query, params).Scan(&id)`

vs

`result, err = tx.Exec(query, params)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're inserting a single row use `QueryRow` - it is designed for, at most, one row update.

If you are performing multi-command updates/queries with multiple results, use `Exec`. The row results from `Exec` need to be closed after row iteration has completed.

So for ease of use & if you know you're only manipulating one row, go with `QueryRow`.

Comment: `Exec` returns result `sql.Result` and not `*sql.Rows`, there is no way to iterate through `sql.Result`. `tx.Query` will return `*sql.Rows` for closing and iteration.

Comment: how queryRow would handle tx.RollBack() and tx.Commit() ??

Answer (score 13):

Generally for reading 1 row use `QueryRow()`

```
err := tx.QueryRow(`Select col from t where col=$1`, "val").Scan(&colholder)
```

For manipulating data via `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `INSERT` etc. Use `Exec`

```
result, err := tx.Exec(`Delete from t where col=$1`, "val")
```

As you can see there is nothing to scan in `Exec` because that is execution and not query.

However no one is stopping you from `QueryRow` for `Exec` operation, or vice versa but it will not be intended purpose. You might lose under the hood optimization for each type of operation.
Also if you use `QueryRow` for `Exec`, you will get `sql.ErrNoRows` error because there is no row to return in `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE`.

Similarly you will not be able to get value from `Exec` as it returns response which can not be `.Scan`ned, if you use query operation in `Exec`.

However there are cases for using `QueryRow` for `Exec` operations

```
err := tx.QueryRow(`Delete from t where col=$1 returning id`, "val").Scan(&deletedID)
```

You just decide if you want a return value from sql operation, use `QueryRow` else use `Exec`.

In your case if you want some data back like id after insert operation use `QueryRow`, otherwise `Exec` suits just fine.